# Why after redirection the page style is off with a huge white space

Tags: css, angular, redirect

I am currently debugging an issue on a login page after resetting user's password. The login page's style is off after user resets their password successfully and clicks the 'change password' button to redirect to the main login page.

The first code section is for my typescript code which will redirect to my local host, for example localhost:44332/login, login page. And the first html code is for my resetting password code, while the second html code is for my main login page.

```js
 resetPassword() {
    if (this.isPermittedToUpdate) {
      if (this.passwordForm.dirty && this.passwordForm.valid) {
        this.spinnerService.show();
        const newPassword = this.passwordForm.get('newPwd').value;

        this.userService.ResetPassword(newPassword, this.urlIdentifier).subscribe(result => {

          if (result.retCode === APIReturnEnum.Successful) {
            this.toastrService.success('Password has been updated');
            this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
          }
```

```html
<div class="row" style="padding-left:2%;padding-bottom: 1%">
  <h1>
    Reset Password
  </h1>
  <hr />

</div>

<div *ngIf="isPermittedToUpdate">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <div class="dashboard_graph x_panel">

        <div class="x_content" style="margin-top:0 !important; padding: 0px !important">
          <form [formGroup]="passwordForm" class="form-horizontal" role="form" style="margin-top:2%"
            (ngSubmit)="resetPassword()">

            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label col-sm-1" style="width:150px">New Password</label>
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input class="form-control" type="password" formControlName="newPwd" name="newPwd"
                  placeholder="Enter your new password here" style="width:80%" />
                <app-validationmessage [control]="passwordForm.controls.newPwd"></app-validationmessage>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label col-sm-1" style="width:150px">Confirm New Password</label>
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input class="form-control" type="password" formControlName="confirmNewPwd" name="confirmNewPwd"
                  placeholder="Confirm your new Password here" style="width:80%" />
                <app-validationmessage [control]="passwordForm.controls.confirmNewPwd"></app-validationmessage>
              </div>

            </div>


            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" style="margin-left:150px; margin-top: 20px;"
            [disabled]="!isPermittedToUpdate">Change Password
            </button>


          </form>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```html
<div class="login1">
  <div class="login_wrapper">
    <section class="login_content">

      <div class="login-container-wrapper">
     

        <ng-container *ngIf="!isPasswordReset; else forgotPassword">

          <h1 class="welcome">Welcome, please login</h1>
          <form class="form-horizontal login-form" [formGroup]="signForm"
                (submit)="submit(email.value, password.value)">
            <div class="form-group-login">
              <div class="relative">
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input type="text" id="email" formControlName="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" #email
                        style="background-color:#fff !important;" />
                <i class="fa fa-user fa-2x"></i>
              </div>
              <app-validationmessage class="form-error" [control]="signForm.controls.email"></app-validationmessage>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group-login">
              <div class="relative password">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" id="password" formControlName="password" class="form-control"
                        placeholder="Password" #password style="background-color:#fff !important;" />
                <i class="fa fa-lock fa-2x"></i>
              </div>
              <app-validationmessage class="form-error" [control]="signForm.controls.password"></app-validationmessage>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group-login log">
              <button type="submit" class="btn dark-grey">Log in</button>
            </div>
            <div class="forgot-pwd">
              <a (click)="switchView()">Forgot Password?</a>
            </div>
          
          </form>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-template #forgotPassword>

          <p>Please enter the email address you registered with Softchoice</p>

          <form [formGroup]="confirmEmailForm" (submit)="sendResetPasswordEmail()">
            <div class="form-group-login">
              <input type="email" class="form-control" formControlName="email" placeholder="">
              <app-validationmessage [control]="confirmEmailForm.controls.email"></app-validationmessage>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group-login">
              <button type="submit" class="btn dark-grey">Send</button>
            </div>

            <div class="forgot-pwd">
              <a (click)="goBackToLogin()"> Go back to Login Page</a>
            </div>

            <div>
         
            </div>
          </form>

        </ng-template>

      </div>
      <!--</form>-->
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Yishmeray Thanks, appreciate that. I will find some way to make the issue simpler. But as you can see my plaintext description and screenshot have helped others understanding my problem. The whole issue is simple, just an extra white space after redirection; however, I don't like to be tagged as an anti-code-favored user with only screenshots. It happened.